# Writing python client for SOAP with suds

Tags: python, soap, https, suds

I want to convert a perl SOAP client into a python SOAP client.
The perl client is initialized like

```
$url = 'https://host:port/cgi-devel/Service.cgi';
$uri = 'https://host/Service';

my $soap = SOAP::Lite 
    -> uri($uri)
    -> proxy($url);
```

I tried to replicate this in python 2.4.2 with suds 0.3.6 doing

```
from suds.client import Client

url="https://host:port/cgi-devel/Service.cgi" 
client=Client(url)
```

However when running this python script I get the error

```
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 411: Length Required
```

Is it because of https or what might be the problem?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I opened a ticket about the issue at the suds webpage some time ago (see https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/259), but got no response so far. Since I'm not using SOAP anymore in my project, the question has become obsolete for me.

Answer (score 3):

`urllib2` module doesn't add Content-Length (required for POST method) header automatically when Request object is constructed manually as `suds` does. You have to patch suds, probably `suds.transport.HttpTransport.open()` method or `suds.transport.Request` class.

Comment: Based on your tips I actually managed to get rid of the error message. But I still could not connect to the server. Later it became clear that, instead of SOAP, I could use another very simple method to connect to the server in question. So I'm not using SOAP anymore, therefore the question has become obsolete for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, then switched to using a local WSDL file, this worked:

```
import suds
wsdl = 'file:///tmp/my.wsdl'
client = suds.client.Client(wsdl, username='lbuser', password='lbpass', location='https://path.to.our.loadbalancer:9090/soap')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask this in the suds's mailing list. This library is under development, is open source, and the authors are very keen to get feedback from the users.

Your code looks fine, this could be an error of the wsdl itself or of the suds library, therefore I encourage you to ask the author directly (after having checked with other wsdls that your installation is correct).